# No white space to be displayed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Goal:
Display any any special charactor based on regex code.

Problem:
If I have two words and between them I have a a white space, then it displays in the table based on the regex code.

It should not display in the table if you have any space between two or many words.

What part am I missing?

Thank you!

```
Create Table #TempTable
(
    City nvarchar(50)
)

truncate table #TempTable

INSERT INTO #TempTable
(City) 
VALUES
('Holte'),
('København S'),
('København S København'),
('Holte'),
('Birkerød-Ruteplan'),
('Birkerød Ruteplan');
    SELECT
        a.*
    FROM 
        #TempTable a
    WHERE 
        (a.City like '%[^a-ZÅÄÖÆæØåäöøæ-]%')
```

Comment: Your expected output should be...

Comment: If you don't want space to be treated as a special character, then shouldn't you simply add space to your list of non-special characters? `'%[^ a-ZÅÄÖÆæØåäöøæ-]%'`

Comment: I gave a new try and this time it works %[^a-ZÅÄÖÆæØåäöøæ -]%. NOt using this regex %[^a-ZÅÄÖÆæØåäöøæ- ]%

Comment: @What'sUP It should be obvious that the `-` must be the last (or first) character in the character class; putting a space (or any other character) behind it will radically change its behavior (and that of the two neighboring characters).